# Create and set scratch fGDB

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, scratch-workspace

I need set the new created fGDB as current for save all FC:

```
import arcpy
import os
out_folder_path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (0)
out_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (1)
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management (out_folder_path, out_name)
arcpy.AddMessage ("fGDB created")
# Set fGDB created as scratch workspace
arcpy.env.scratchGDB = out_folder_path + "/" + out_name + ".gdb"
arcpy.AddMessage ("fGDB set current (scratchGDB)")
```

But I receive the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Python_ArcGIS_MasterSIG\Proyecto_Final\Codigo\Crear_fGDB.py", line 30, in <module>
    arcpy.env.scratchGDB = out_folder_path + "/" + out_name + ".gdb"
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 541, in set_
    self[env] = val
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 601, in __setitem__
    ret_ = setattr(self._gp, item, value)
AttributeError: Object: Environment <scratchGDB> cannot be set

Failed to execute (CrearfGDB)
```

What is the mistake?

Comment: The `scratchGDB` property is listed as being "Read Only" and the referenced page's [Usage Notes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/environments/scratch-gdb.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_1CC6992B678B45188A259370E6FF100C) reports *The Scratch GDB environment is read-only; you cannot set the location directly.*

Answer (score 1):

As @Vince points out, the `scratchGDB` environment is read-only. However, you can use `arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace` instead.

- Documentation for [scratchWorkspace](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/environments/scratch-workspace.htm) (read/write).
- Documentation for [scratchGDB](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/environments/scratch-gdb.htm) (read-only).
- Documentation for [scratchFolder](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/environments/scratch-folder.htm) (read-only).